# Flume HDFS sink partition by event time

Tags: flume

I use Flume to receive access log from Kafka and write to HDFS directories partitioned by time. The "time" here, as far as I understand, is "processing time", and I want to partition by "event time".

For instance, logs like the following should be partitioned into `dt=20170627`, even if it is received late in 20170628:

```
0.123 [2017-06-27 09:08:00] GET /
0.234 [2017-06-27 09:08:01] GET /
```

I know Hive sink can partition by a field extracted from records, but it requires the records are delimited or in json format.

Thanks.